# I am having trouble getting a URL to switch in this windows forms program

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

The program has a label, two radio buttons, and a set of generated buttons from A-Z. There are two URLs I would like to use that have a text list of names. When You click a lettered button, the program splits the text list and displays them in the label.

The two radio buttons are supposed to switch the URL being used. One URL has male first names, the other url has female first names. However, I am not sure how to get this to work...as I have it now, choosing the radio button does nothing... it will stay on whatever the first URL was.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace IndexTable
{
    public partial class frmIndex : Form
    {
        public frmIndex()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = sender as Button; // Convert datatype 
            label1.Text = btn.Text + "\n"; ;
            foreach (string c in name)
            {

                if (c != "" && c.Substring(0, 1) == btn.Text)
                {
                    label1.Text += c + "\n";
                    //listBox1.Items.Add(c);
                }
            }

        }
        string[] name;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int top = 10;
            int left = 20;
            int width = 30;

            for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'M'; i++)
            {
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Left = left;
                button.Top = top;
                button.Width = width;
                button.Text = i.ToString();
                this.Controls.Add(button);
                button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Click);
                top += button.Height + 2;
            }

            left = 50;
            top = 10;

            for (char i = 'N'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
            {
                Button button = new Button();
                button.Left = left;
                button.Top = top;
                button.Width = width;
                button.Text = i.ToString();
                this.Controls.Add(button);
                button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Button_Click);
                top += button.Height + 2;
            }


            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            string names = wc.DownloadString(url);
            name = names.Split('\n');

        }

        private string url = "http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/areas/nlp/corpora/names/male.txt";

        private void btnBoy_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            url = "http://scrapmaker.com/data/wordlists/names/male-names.txt";

        }

        private void btnGirl_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            url = "http://scrapmaker.com/data/wordlists/names/female-names.txt";

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The CheckedChanged event fires whether the button becomes checked or becomes unchecked. Therefore you need to add a line of code to see what the current check state of the button is before responding:

```
private void btnBoy_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnBoy.Checked)
        url = "http://scrapmaker.com/data/wordlists/names/male-names.txt";
}
```

EDIT: also you only use the url once, in the form load event, with the line

```
wc.DownloadString(url)
```

You'll need to add code to actually use the url again after you change it with the radiobuttons--either in the radiobutton event handler, or the other button event handler for instance.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Probably because you don't use the url after that! See my edited answer for suggestions on that.